# low-memory high-speed replacement for Picard MarkDuplicates

Tags: sam, samtools, sambamba, picard

I am running Picard MarkDuplicates with the following parameters below. On the file described, it takes about 41.6Gb of RAM memory and about 20-25 minutes to compute (only uses 1 core AFAICS).

```
java -Xmx54890m -jar picard.jar MarkDuplicates \
    I=/home/dnanexus/in/sorted_bam/TST73-86-2IC_S16_L00.bml.GRCh38.karyo.bam \
    O=./TST73-86-2IC_S16_L00.bml.GRCh38.karyo.deduplicated.bam \
    M=./TST73-86-2IC_S16_L00.bml.GRCh38.karyo.duplication_metrics \
    CREATE_INDEX=true VALIDATION_STRINGENCY=SILENT REMOVE_DUPLICATES=true
```

What equivalent free/open source software (samtools?, sambamba?) can I use to obtain the same deduplicated bam file but at a lower cost, considering the instance used here has 8 cores but only one of them is being used, and has about 68Gb of RAM out of which it's using 46Gb odd at peak.

I think previous versions of samtools/sambamba didn't behave the same way as Picard MarkDuplicates with the parameters above, but I would like to know which recent versions would give me the same output.

Comment: I assume you only want free (in terms of price, at least) software, right? [Sentieon](http://sentieon.com/) have a tool for this that is orders of magnitude faster (and I would guess uses less RAM but I'd have to check) but you need to pay for it.

Comment: Correct, open source.

Comment: I done no benchmark, but I guess [samblaster](https://github.com/GregoryFaust/samblaster) is bit faster (by my subjective perception of time).

Comment: You should specify a smaller "-Xmx". MarkDuplicate doesn't need that much memory, but seeing a large "-Xmx", java will use extra.

Answer (score 2):

As you suggested, sambamba is faster at marking duplicates than picard (it's also multithreaded). Recent versions of samtools have a rewritten duplicate marking algorithm, though I doubt it'll be as quick as sambamba. 46GB of RAM seems excessive for marking duplicates unless you're having it store the whole file in memory.

Comment: Does sambamba with default parameters equate to Picard MarkDuplicates?

Comment: I'm not sure that any tool exactly equates (there are a lot of edge cases in duplicate marking and picard misses some things), but it's a sufficient replacement. Sambamba is also used for this purpose by a number of international consortia (I think either DEEP or IHEC, if I remember correctly).